# Different message on the message box

Tags: visual-studio, message, box, statements

```
    Private Sub btnEval_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEval.Click
            If cbAbuse1.Checked Or cbAbuse2.Checked Then
                If cbBullied1.Checked Or cbBullied2.Checked Then
                    If cbDeprsn1.Checked Or cbDeprsn2.Checked Then
                        If cbGrief_Loss1.Checked Or cbGrief_Loss2.Checked Then
                            If cbSH1.Checked Or cbSH2.Checked Then
                                If cbStrsd1.Checked Or cbStrsd2.Checked Then
                                Else
                                End If
                           End If
                       End If
                   End If
               End If
           End If
       End Sub
```

So this is my code, after I click the "btnEval" button it should show a message box with a different message depending on what check box is checked.

Comment: But since you are posting here, I'm guessing that's not what happens... Please describe what actually happens/doesn't happen.

Comment: well right now nothing happens when I click the button. And I can't figure out how to display a message box.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking but if you just wanted to know how to display a message box (I am assuming you are using VB.NET here) the code is:

```
Messagebox.Show("This is the content of my message box", "Message box title")
```

Hope that helps :)